# Контроль нагрузки сервера HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, сервер, http

Вопрос к тем, кто имел дело с задачей написания HTTP-сервера, в частности с использованием класса `HttpListener`.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ определить текущую нагрузку, чтобы временно прекратить обработку запроссов, и дать серверу разгрузиться? Понятно что у нас есть `SetRequestProcessingLimits`, но он контролирует количество открытых и ожидающих запросов, а они бывают разными. Простых можно обработать и тысячу/сек.

Хотелось контролировать именно по динамике времени на запрос или, как таковой, нагрузке. И я понимаю, что можно придумать много чего через системные функции, но меня интересует опыт тех, кто сталкивался с этой задачей - каким путём пошли вы, или каким ходить принято?

Вот, для примера, простейшая структура. Как это можно сделать в её рамках, например?

```
public async void Start() 
{

    listener.Start(); 
    while (true) 
    { 
    try 
    { 
    HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync(); 
    Task.Run(() => ProcessRequestAsync(context)); 
    } 
    catch (HttpListenerException) { break; } 
    }

}

async void ProcessRequestAsync(HttpListenerContext context) 
{
    //код обработки запроса
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под нагрузкой? Ресурсы cpu/диска/сети?

Comment: Действительно, не уточнил. Имеются ввиду ресурсы CPU.